# Two dimensional HTML form inputs

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, dynamic

So basically I have the following HTML form:

```
<form>
    <div class="Question">
        <input name="question" type="text"></input>

        <div class="alternatives">
            <input type="text" name="TextAlternative[]"></input>
            <input type="text" name="TextAlternative[]"></input>
        </div>
        <a href="#\" class="newTextAlternative_click">New Alternative</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#\" class="newTextQuestion_click"></a>
</form>
```

I am working on an online poll application and I want to give the user the ability to define a series of questions along with an array of alternatives for each question.

A click on the *newTextAlternative_click* generates a new alternative input field. Thanks to the bracket notation in the name of the alternatives input *TextAlternative[]* I can just request all the alternatives of a question in the form of an array.

The problem occurs when I generate another *Question* div. I want to be able to request the inputs for each question as an array, so I tried to do the following:

```
<input name="question[]" type="text"></input>
```

This gives me the possibility to request the *question* for each question defined as an array. However i'm in trouble with the alternatives now.

I want to be able to request the alternatives as follows:

```
Question[i]Alternative[i]
```

Without having to hardcode it like this:

```
<input name="Alternative[0][]"></input>
```

The reason for this is that I provide the user with the ability to delete one of the questions within the form again, same for the alternatives. I'd prefer to not loop the dom each time and change all of the array indices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's your question?  You can do answers like `answer[questionIndex][alternativeIndex]`. You don't need to have a continuous sequence of indexes. So deletion does not mean to reindex whole array of answers.

Comment: instead of having `Alternative[0][]` you can better have `Alternative-0[]` so while adding new rows you will make the name part dynamic by concatenating the question index. this way you will have to play with single array and for each question you will have array of its alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using using javascript. On submit I'm having a script running over the present alternatives and parse it to a JSON object to ease process it at the backend.